# Golang css serve

Tags: css, go

I hope you don't find my question stupid, but I really couldn't find an answer.

I am trying to serve my style.css file, but it won't work.

This is the structure of the project:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIQGo.png)

In the css file i have: "link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"/"

In the mainn.go I am trying to serve the css file using this: router.Handle("/css/", http.StripPrefix("/css/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("/hpages"))))

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/hpages` is an absolute path. Maybe try `./hpages` instead.

The following program, run on my local machine works:

```golang
package main

import (
  "log"
  "net/http"
)

func main() {
  router := http.NewServeMux()
  router.Handle("/css/", http.StripPrefix("/css/",
                http.FileServer(http.Dir("./hpages"))))
  log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":5000", router))
}
```

Comment: Hey, Ive included an example that I've tried and that works. Could you check if that works on your local machine?

Comment: Hello, I've done the exact same thing, but the page shows like it would't have any css at all

Comment: Can you check your browser network tab to see if the file was received by the browser.

Comment: Yup, they weren't, found out that I was handling "/style.css" like a regular page, so of course it would not work, but now, thanks to your "./hpages" it works. Thanks a lot !